# Modifying Bootstrap @media

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eofyztpq/1/) that shows a menu using bootstrap. When resizing the browser, I would like the menu to collapse before the links on the right fall below the brand on the left. What I would like to know is should I modify the @media section in bootstrap.css, or is there another way to collapse my menu without changing the default bootstrap CSS? Am I asking for trouble later on if I change the default media bootstrap.css file?

Section in Bootstrap.css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {  /* If I change this to 825, I achieve what I 
                                want. Is that the best way, or am I asking
                                for trouble later on? */
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also [generate a custom bootstrap css file from their website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) and set a new value for the `screen-sm`breakpoint. This would take care of resizing everything at your desired screen width instead of the default 768px.

Comment: Just what I need...especially since there are other things I will need to be changing.

Comment: Didn't realise you could do that, although I still would have stuck with custom queries in another stylesheet. Alot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the Bootstrap rules alone, and just create additional rules that suit your needs in another stylesheet, but make sure this additional CSS file is called AFTER the bootstrap one, so they can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the section you want to edit from bootstrap and paste+edit it in a new css file with the `min-width` at 825px. Editing bootstrap itself gets messy, it's better to just override it with new css.